# Android how to place a layout on top of two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

The layout should be align half on 1st layout bottom and half on second layouts top, i didn't got any clue on my searching. anyone help me![image: ![See the image for better idea]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a6rl.jpg)

Comment: Its easy bro...Firstly what have you tried??

Comment: Have you done any initial codes? Can you post it? And to clearly answer the question.. Just Use ***RelativeLayout*** as the main parent layout.

Comment: Framelayout can be used to create this . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work correct across all resolutions -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does work for all resolution, one point tho, I edited it out to remove the outermost RelativeLayout. Just waiting for reviewer to confirm it.. :)

Comment: Yup !!! works fine. I wanted this for portrait mode only. Thank you @Jyotman Singh

Answer (score 3):

So I went ahead and tried this out, and managed to do something like this..

[image]

Here is a simple code to help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For more information regarding how to use a RelativeLayout, you can check the Official Android Developers Site - [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Amit Vaghela Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry @sept but I don't know why this is getting upvotes. This is wrong. Setting marginBottom 50dp to get the layout in center is just a fluke. It will come at different positions in different resolution phones.

Comment: @Jyotman Singh This is just a simple code snippet to point them to the right direction. The question is just on **how**, they weren't asking for the exact codes. It's up to the one who asked the question on how they'll implement it. ;)